# Packaging HTML as a "browser file"

Tags: html, file, browser, types, archive

I've recently began using Sphinx to generate documents and slides (and love it).  Though I don't always want to "publish" my content on a site.

My question: is there an existing mechanism to archive HTML content so that when opened on the  PC the browser is the default application which understands it's an archive with an 'index.html' as the starting point?  This would save the user the steps of unzipping and opening the index.html.

TIA!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [EXEOutput](http://www.exeoutput.com/) for PHP, which does the work for you.

- Convert PHP scripts, websites, JavaScript, HTML, databases into stand-alone apps for Windows (single EXE files) that do not require a Web server nor PHP distribution.
- Make Fully-Customizable Applications for the Desktop with PHP, HTML and JavaScript, and without additional skills.

---

Another one is [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/)! This is exactly what you're looking for.

It comes in mac and linux flavors. I'd highly recommend it. Best part is that its [free for Indies](https://awesomium.com/buy/)! :D

Comment: Thanks for the solutions.  I was hoping there'd be some accepted browser featured that solved the problem.  In my research since asking the question, I've come across MHTML and WEBARC.  At least MHTML only addresses a single document (i.e. links are external).

Comment: So it does cover the case where HTML may be packed into a single document (like HTML5 slides).  But yes, doesn't cover all of my cases. :/

Comment: What cases doesn't it cover?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry.  I wasn't clear.  I was agreeing with you that MHTML doesn't cover all of the use cases.  Ideally the solution would be inherently supported by (most) browsers.  But your native solutions may be the only option.